# How do I get rows with same values in 2 columns who match a condition and with a different value in the other two

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, python-3.6

I have a dataframe that looks like this example below:

```
          A      B     C   D  E 
    1    foo    one    0   1  0
    2    foo    one    1   2  1
    ..........
    103  foo    two    2   3  1
    54   foo    two    3   4  1
    ..........
    25   bar    three  4  15  0
    96   bar    three  5  16  1
    ..........
    67   bar    four   6  17  0
    111  bar    five   7  18  1
```

My expected output:

```
          A      B     C   D  E 
    1    foo    one    0   1  0
    2    foo    one    1   2  1
    ..........
    25   bar    three  4  15  0
    96   bar    three  5  16  1
    ..........
```

Explanation:
*(This is two dataframes concatenated atop each other and column E identifies which set a particular row is from, **`0` for "set_0" and `1` for "set_1"**. I now want to look at the rows that have same values for all the columns in both the dataframes, except two columns.)*

In rows with index 1 & 2, I have same values for columns A and B, for set_1 and set_0, but with different values in C & D. So, these are the columns I want to look at. And in rows with index 103 & 54, rows for columns A and B does match, but are from same set. So, I don't want these rows. In rows with index 25 and 96, I have same values in columns A and B, fro set_1 and set_0. So, I want these rows. And rows with index 67 and 111, have different values in columns A and B, but, belong to different sets, so i don't want these rows.

I have tried `groupby` and `drop_duplicates`, but I can't get the part where I want to query the rows that belong to different datasets, denoted by 0 and 1 of column E.
How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible test if each group by `A,B` column has 2 different unique values in `E` column use:

```
df = df[df.groupby(['A','B'])['E'].transform('nunique').eq(2)]
```

Comment: what does `.eq(2)` do? what is it for?

Comment: @NaveenKumar - It compare if 2 unique values, here `0, 1`